# Name of the sliding property?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to know how to make that effect where there are little navigation circles in the right side of the screen, and when you click one of them, It scrolls to another section of the webpage. And so with the other ones. It's like a scrolling navigation between little circles.
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) or [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) plugins. They might provide you some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check some tutorials first, there are plenty, I think this one is pretty good:
http://www.adriantomic.se/development/jquery-localscroll-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement this kind of behavior, where you click on a link and it goes to another section of the page, is with `a` tags and relative links.

For example, if I have an `a` tag at the top of the page:

```
<a href="#bananas">Go to "Bananas"</a>
```

At some point down the page, I have:

```
<h2 id="bananas">All about bananas</h2>
```

If I click the first link, my browser will automatically go to the `h2`, since it has `id` of `bananas`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an additional JQuery Plugin. Try this one: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/